# How to avoid splitting a word over two UITextViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I guess this is a slightly awkward question, so let me rephrase it with an illustration:
[image]

I have an UITextView which is limited to a certain amount of chars. This is regularly checked with `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString *)aText`. Once the text is larger than the thresh hold (in the illustration it would be 8 chars), the app changes to the next textView and copies the next char entered (in this case p) to the new UITextView. The user can then enters the rest of the word (in this case py).

Instead of splitting the word over two UITextViews, I would like to have the entire word 'happy' in the next UITextView. In other words, I need to copy the 'hap' from string 1 to the beginning of string 2 and then delete 'hap' from string 1.

I came up with this code which checks string 1 for spaces and copies everything after a space into string 2. But it won't work:

```
NSLog(@"text of current string: %@", aTextView.text);           // e.g. "I am hap"
         NSLog(@"chars in aTextView.text: %i", aTextView.text.length);  // e.g. 8 chars
         NSLog(@"text for next string: %@ ", aText);                    // e.g. "py"

         NSString *aTextModified = aText;

         for (int i = aTextView.text.length; i > 0; i--) {

             NSLog(@"I currently check: '@%'", [aTextView.text characterAtIndex:i]);

             if ([[aTextView.text characterAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@" "]) {
                 // job done
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"I add %@ infront of %@", [aTextView.text characterAtIndex:i], aText);
                 aTextModified = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [aTextView.text characterAtIndex:i], aText];
                 NSLog(@"I delete %@ as I have put it into the next string...", [aTextView.text characterAtIndex:i]);
                 [aTextView.text characterAtIndex:i] = @"";
             }
         }
```

XCode gives me the warning 'Invalid receiver type 'unichar'' for the line `if ([[aTextView.text characterAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@" "])`. I guess I'm not using the characterAtIndex right? Am I not allowed to apply this to a text (which should be an UIString) in an UITextView?

Also, I get the error 'LValue required as left opperand of assignement' for the last line `[aTextView.text characterAtIndex:i] = @"";` Again, I guess I don't really understand how to access a char in an UITextView and modify it.

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions of how to do this right - and if there are easier ways to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Comment: what happens if a word is larger than the threshold?

Comment: @Nick Weaver: Well, it can't be larger than the threshold as it will be automatically cut off. E.g. if you try to enter 'areallylongword' it will be cut off after 'areallylo' and the 'n' will be put in the next string. I check the string after every character entered. Also, my strings 1 and 2 are much larger than 8 chars -- I've just taken it for illustration purposes to keep things simple. In reality, I am looking at an entire UITextView filling the screen... The problem is checking the last word entered on this screen and if it needs to be put on the next screen. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things

```
NSLog(@"I currently check: '@%'", [aTextView.text characterAtIndex:i]);
```

You get a `C` character here so you should be using `%c` instead.

```
[[aTextView.text characterAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@" "]
```

Again, what you're doing here is sending a message to a `C` character which is incorrect. You can change it to `[aTextView.text characterAtIndex:i] == " "` to do it correctly.

```
[aTextView.text characterAtIndex:i] = @"";
```

`text` is defined as an immutable string. You can't change it like this. You will have to declare a mutable string and copy the contents of `text` over. After modifications to the mutable string, you can set it to `text`.

This will also give you the last word.

```
NSScanner *wordsScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"I am happy however I want the last word and it's positions !!!!"];
NSString *theLastWord;
while (![wordsScanner isAtEnd]) {
    [wordsScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] intoString:&theLastWord];
}

// theLastWord has the value.
```

**EDIT**

```
NSString *text = aTextView.text;
int index = text.length - 1;
while ([text characterAtIndex:index] != " ") {
    index--;
}

NSString stringToBeMoved = [text substringFromIndex:index];
aTextView.text = [text substringToIndex:(index+1)];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try and let you know how it went.

Comment: Actually, I am a bit confused about declaring a mutable string and then copying the contents of text over... how will I do this? Simply `Char replacementChar = "";` and then `[aTextView.text characterAtIndex:i] = replacementChar;` wouldn't work, right?

Answer (score 1):

Ok let's start out simple. I've created the following regular expression which will match the last word in a string and if there is non word characters like white spaces or punctuation marks.

I think it's easier to work with a regex and determine on where it matches to manipulate the string. However I am not sure how performance will be in large texts, but I think that can be solved by using some assumptions like: textview one won't skip within the first 1000 characters so it may be safe to use only the last 50 characters for the regex.

```
NSString *aString = @"I am happy however I want the last word and it's positions !!!!";

NSString * const regularExpression = @"\\b(\\w+)\\b(\\W*)$";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regularExpression
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionUseUnicodeWordBoundaries
                                                                         error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:aString
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [aString length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    for (int i = 0; i < [match numberOfRanges]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"substring %d: %@", i, [aString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:i]]);
    }
}
```

If it matches you can easily iterate through the result which gives you the last word and some trailing non word characters, but most important is that you get the range of each match so you can determine if a threshold is crossed.

Comment: Thanks Nick. But I guess the problem is that I don't get a complete string. I only get a character at a time! Remember that I am using `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString *)aText` -- so I only get aText which is usually one char only. In other words, the app constantly checks while you type each char. If you try to add another char and cross the thresh hold, I want to separate the beginning of the last word I tried to enter (e.g. positi -- ons I couldn't enter any more). I want 'positi' copied into the next UITextView.

Comment: I will try to work in your code and let you know where I got stuck. I guess my biggest problem is that I'm not using NSMakeRange...

Comment: @n.evermind well you could switch to the delegate method `textViewDidChange` and just use myTextField.text as input, so the check happens every time a user hits a key.